# Get OutputStream from already running process

Tags: linux

I want to write to the stdin of a running process (not Java). How can I get the `Process` object or the `OutputStream` directly? `Runtime.getRuntime()` only helps me spawn new things, not find existing processes.

Comment: your title says Get OutputStream but your description says how to write to the stdin. So which one it is ?

Comment: I don't think what you want to do is possible.

Comment: I think you will need to use shared memory or pipes to communicate between processes. Could be wrong though, maybe others will correct me.

Comment: @MauricioGracia In javaland the outputstream of a process is the stdin

Comment: Not exactly. When you create a process yourself, Java creates an output stream and connects its output to the stdin of that process. Java's own stdin is `System.in` which is definitely not an `OutputStream`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I think OP means that, from Java's point of view, you're writing to a `Process` `OutputStream` which corresponds to that process' standard input.

Comment: So this is not really java related at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks possible on Linux, no idea about elsewhere.  Searching for ["get stdin of running process"](https://www.google.com/search?q=get%20stdin%20of%20running%20process) revealed several promising looking discussions:

- [Writing to stdin of background process](https://serverfault.com/questions/188936/writing-to-stdin-of-background-process)
- [Write to stdin of a running process using pipe](https://serverfault.com/questions/443297/write-to-stdin-of-a-running-process-using-pipe)
- [Can I send some text to the STDIN of an active process running in a screen session?](https://serverfault.com/questions/178457/can-i-send-some-text-to-the-stdin-of-an-active-process-running-in-a-screen-sessi)

Essentially, you can write to the 0th file descriptor of a process via `/proc/$pid/fd/0`.  From there, you just have to open an `OutputStream` to that path.

I just tested this (not the Java part, that's presumably straightforward) and it worked as advertized:

```
Shell-1 $ cat
```

This blocks, waiting on stdin

```
Shell-2 $ ps aux | grep 'cat$' | awk '{ print $2 }'
1234
Shell-2 $ echo "Hello World" > /proc/1234/fd/0
```

Now back in Shell-1:

```
Shell-1 $ cat
Hello World
```

Note this does not close the process's stdin.  You can keep writing to the file descriptor.